# How can I improve performance on the Windows PC which I use as a backup & file server?

Tags: windows-10, performance

I am using this desktop as a file server & backup. It runs Windows 10, and has 2 internal & 4 external drives. Windows runs from an internal SSD and the swap file is on the other internal (non-SSD hard drive).

It runs painfully slowly when it is occasionally used as a PC. E.g the printer & scanner are attached to it, so scanning is sloooow; sometimes we have reason to use it with MS Office. What can I do to upgrade it and improve performance?

As cheaply as possible :-)  I.E no RAID, etc.

If I must buy a new PC, this one is backing up 12+ tB of data. If a new PC is required, it would be nice to use the existing case, as it has a motherboard that supports 4 @ SATA (the other drives are external, USB3).

But, if it is cheaper, then a totally new PC with only 2 SATA drive support - one SSD for Windows and a large (12+ tB) drive might work out cheaper.

Since Windows is already on SSD, I can't see how to improve that. Would more RAM help? New CPU (do you need details of the motherboard for that)? Maybe run a different o/s? But there are reasons to keep it with Windows.

If you need more info to be able to help me, please ask.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why, oh why, are you putting the Windows 10 swap file on a spinning rust disk? Is it because you think the writes to swap will "wear out" the SSD? if so, that is a myth.

Comment: Pretty much all "full size" motherboards that I've seen have _at least_ 4 SATA ports. (In the worst case, add a PCIe card with a second SATA controller, those usually have a ton of ports.) And don't forget about being able to put SSDs in M.2 slots (directly or via PCIe adapter)... But, I'm searching about A6-7400K and it seems to be a dual-core CPU, so why does your Task Manager only show "Cores: 1"? Also, what is occupying _so much_ RAM on your system?

Comment: The reason your server is so slow is due to the fact your server has a single processor core.  I am pretty sure the minimum requirement for Windows 10 is to have at least dual cores.  We will of course be unable to provide hardware recommendations.  If you actually do have the swap, on a spinning mechanical drive, that would be a major source of a performance bottleneck.  You would basically eliminate most of the performance gains from a SDD by doing that.

Comment: For Socket FM2+, it looks like the fastest processor you can get is the Athlon X4 880K -  as long as the motherboard BIOS is upgraded before installing it *and* supports that processor. However, any of the Athlon X4 processors, which have four cores, would be an improvement. Make sure the processor heatsink is up to the job.

Comment: Thanks and upvotes for the comme so far.  Swap file is on the other  dusk as I seem to recall  reading that it made access faster. Would it be better  on the same SSD drive as Windows? On its own partition? I Will look at the dual/sing core and report back what it has  / is using. I Will look into RAM usage

Comment: I had a Samsung Evo 840 (120 Gb) SSD on my desktop PC running Windows 10 for 5 years, with the swap on the SSD. I just specified "Automatically manage" in the Virtual Memory settings. Everything worked fine and I only changed the drive one year ago (it still works in a laptop) because a WD Blue 1 TB drive was a nice price and I needed more space. Swap on another drive may make access a bit faster but NOT if the system drive is an SSD and the swap is on a spinning drive.

Comment: The swap is `c:\pagefile.sys` and is 800 MB in size.

Comment: Where did you see that?  For me, C: says "no paging file", but a dedicated partition on the hard drive is 10,800 mB.  Should I move it to the SDD, even though that's where Windows is? And what's the recommended ratio of RAM to page file size?

Comment: For cores, see the last of 2  answers [here](https://community.amd.com/t5/processors/a6-7400k-com-1-n%C3%BAcleo/td-p/214633). It says that it has 2 cores, but Windows only "sees" 1. There is no single RAM hog, just a bunch of stuff, but 10gB used from 16 seems to be no problem

Comment: Mawg, there have been pages of "tips" about page files since before Windows 2000. Magic formulas, for max & min size, etc. It's all hooey. Let Windows manage it automatically. You should move it to the SDD, **because** that's where Windows is.